# Logback. Storing only current day's logs

Tags: java, logging, logback, appender, rollingfileappender

I'm using logback in my project. I have the issue storing only current day's logs. 
My logback appender config:

```
<appender name="appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>log/log.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>log/log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>512MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{66} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

I want to see files log.2017-06.22.0.zip, log.2017-06.22.1.zip .. if current date is 2017-06-22. All previous logs must be deleted. If I set maxHistory to 1, I see current day logs and previous day logs. Please help me.

Comment: What are you trying  to achieve ? What is your business need ? With your setup you are getting only one history file, with a max size of 512 Mb per file. If your app generates more than 1g of logs in one day, you are losing logs for the current day (if you enter a deadly loop you'll quickly have logs full of stacktraces and a missing first-cause log line).
Similarily, if you delete last day's log, how are you going to diagnose an error which occured at 23:59 ?

Comment: @ibndev I need to have only current day log. I don't have issue to diagnose an error which occured at 23:59. Only current day. From 0:00 to 23:59. Now my app generates logs more than 1g and I have many logs like log.2017-06.22.0.zip, log.2017-06.22.1.zip .. It's ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately with the current version of logback (1.2.3) I don't think this is possible. Check the source code of ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.TimeBasedArchiveRemover to see how parameter maxHistory is used :

```
// below is line 97
void capTotalSize(Date now) {
    long totalSize = 0;
    long totalRemoved = 0;
    for (int offset = 0; offset < maxHistory; offset++) {
        // snip : execute removal
        // notice that if you set maxHistory to 0 or -1 the loop contents will not be executed at all.
    }
    addInfo("Removed  " + new FileSize(totalRemoved) + " of files");
}
```

You may want to file a feature request (or a PR) to the logback project.